# Windows 10 Wi-Fi vs Airplane Mode Security

Tags: wireless, internet, windows-10

Does Windows 10 Airplane Mode provide the same level of security/protection as turning off Wi-Fi?

I know that turning on Airplane Mode disables Bluetooth; however, as far as connecting to the Internet, is there any fundamental security difference in turning off Wi-Fi versus turning on Airplane Mode on my PC running Windows 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Airplane mode turns off all active wireless controllers. So that is both Wi-Fi and Bluetooth.

Once turned off, there is no possibility of any external agent getting into the computer without physical access unless malware or remote management is also present that could be use to turn the wireless controllers back on again.

Turning off the controllers means turning power off which saves battery too.

The same is true of turning off Wi-Fi. So no, there is no difference except that turning off Wi-Fi is likely to only turn off a single wireless controller.

Answer (score 0):

Airplane mode is just a shortcut to disabling all communication. That *includes* Wifi but also disables Bluetooth and other communication forms.

> Airplane mode gives you a quick way to **turn off all wireless communications** on your PC. Some examples of wireless communications are Wi-Fi, cellular, Bluetooth, GPS, and near field communication (NFC).

[(Source)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/ce29965f-021d-45e8-b2c5-fb8e0026cd49/turn-on-airplane-mode)

So airplane mode is a good choice if you want to make sure all wireless communication is turned off at once - but for Wifi in particular there is no difference between turning it off by hand or via airplane mode.